# Choice of two fields with two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT `shop_items`.* 
FROM `shop_items` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `shop_item_properties` ON `shop_items`.`shop_id` = `shop_item_properties`.`shop_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `property_value_ints` ON `shop_items`.`id` = `property_value_ints`.`entity_id` AND `shop_item_properties`.`property_id` = property_value_ints.property_id 
WHERE `shop_group_id` = '835' 
AND 
( 
        ( 
            `shop_item_properties`.`property_id` = '565' 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` >= 1950 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` <= '2011' 
        OR 
            `shop_item_properties`.`property_id` = '566' 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` >= '2011' 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` <= 2016 
        ) 
    OR 
        ( 
            `shop_item_properties`.`property_id` = '565' 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` = 0 
        OR 
            `shop_item_properties`.`property_id` = '566' 
            AND 
            `property_value_ints`.`value` <= '2011' 
        ) 
) 
AND `shop_items`.`deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `shop_items`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(`shop_item_properties`.`id`) = 2
```

What i want. Item has two properies: years of issue e.g. 1950-2010 (property with id 565 = 1950, property 566 = 2010) or 2010-... (property 565 = 0, property 566 = 2010. I know this is a bad decision, but I did not invent) so, I'm looking for an items, which were issued in a given year

Please help me change query between `WHERE shop_group_id = '835'` and `AND shop_items.deleted = 0`, because the rest of the right.

Comment: shop_group_id belongs to which table? And your parentheses are misplaced and/or insufficient

Comment: You might want to stick some more brackets in that query.  Where you have "cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3 OR cond4 AND cond5 AND cond6" then I think you might expect this to be "(cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR (cond4 AND cond5 AND cond6)"; it isn't.

Comment: AND is higher precedent than OR, so add parenthesis correctly

Comment: I changed topic, may be now you understand what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
    ` shop_items `.*
FROM
    ` shop_items `
LEFT OUTER JOIN ` shop_item_properties ` ON ` shop_items `.` shop_id ` = ` shop_item_properties `.` shop_id `
LEFT OUTER JOIN ` property_value_ints ` ON ` shop_items `.` id ` = ` property_value_ints `.` entity_id `
AND ` shop_item_properties `.` property_id ` = property_value_ints.property_id
WHERE
    ` shop_group_id ` = '835'
AND (
        ` shop_item_properties `.` property_id ` = '565'
        AND 
        (
            ` property_value_ints `.`VALUE BETWEEN 1950 AND 2011 OR ` property_value_ints `.`VALUE` = 0
        )
)
OR (
    ` shop_item_properties `.` property_id ` = '566'
    AND 
    (
        ` property_value_ints `.`VALUE BETWEEN 2001 AND 2016 OR ` property_value_ints `.`VALUE` <= 2001

    )
)
AND ` shop_items `.` deleted ` = 0
GROUP BY
    ` shop_items `.` id `
HAVING
    COUNT (
        ` shop_item_properties `.` id `
    ) = 2
```

Comment: No, its wrong. Item have two properies: 
years of issue e.g. 1950-2010 (property 565 = 1950, property 566 = 1950) or 2010-... (property 565 = 0, property 566 = 2010. I know this is a bad decision, but I did not invent)
so, I'm looking for an item, which were issued in a given year

Comment: I changed topic, may be now you understand what I mean.